# Upper bound on the probability of a length $m$ run of heads in $n$ tosses of a coin?

Tags: probability

Let $m = \log_2 n + k$. I am trying to find an upper bound on the probability that there is at least one run of exactly $m$ consecutive heads in $n$ tosses of a fair coin. Let $M_i$ be the event that the coins $i, \cdots, m+i$ turn up heads. Clearly I can bound the probability of interest by $$P(\cup_i M_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-m} P(M_i) = \frac{n-m}{2^m} = \frac{n - \log_2n - k}{n \cdot 2^k} \leq \frac{1}{2^k}.$$

How can I improve this bound? Could someone please provide a hint about other strategies to try? Does the problem simplify if instead I require a bound on the probability of at least one run of *at least* $m$ consecutive heads?

Comment: Your last question seems to imply that "one run of exactly $m$ consecutive heads" requires the run to have a tail (or end of sequence) at each end. Is that so? Say, if $n=4$ and $m=2$, does the sequence $THHH$ qualify or not?